# async-await SyntaxError in decorator aiogram

Tags: python, async-await, syntax-error, python-decorators

Good day everyone, I wrote this code and got a syntax error, because await is outside the asynchronous function

How can I fix this? The library I am using is aiogram, db_lite.get_state() is async def

```
@dp.message_handler(lambda message: await db_lite.get_state(message.from_user.id) == 'wallet')
async def get_wallet(message: types.Message):
    lang_code = 'ru' if await db_lite.get_language(message.from_user.id) == 0 else 'en'
    await db_lite.set_wallet(message.from_user.id, message.text)
    await db_lite.set_state(message.from_user.id, '*')
    await message.answer(
        locality['profile_menu']['wallet']['ready'][lang_code].format(
            await db_lite.get_wallet(message.from_user.id
        )), reply_markup=await profile_menu_keyboard(message.from_user.id))
```

built-in FSM I don't want to use

Comment: `await` is used in statements, but in a `lambda` you can only use expressions. Define a function instead of using a `lambda`!

Answer (score 0):

For this task you need to use

```
dp.loop.run_until_complete(db_lite.get_state(message.from_user.id))
```